# Check location path/search/hash for matching value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings like so: `['foo', 'bar', 'foo/*/test']` and a random URL like this: `http://www.example.com/foo/bar?test=123/another=one#test`.

The URL may or may not contain a query or a hash prop.

Is there a regex or simple functionality to check the URL, in the URL contains any of those values in the array?

I am aware of the `String.prototype.includes` function so we could just do:
`let path = location.pathname` and then `path.includes('foo')`, but I want strings that contain the structure of `foo/*/bar/` to be of higher importance.

For example if the URL is like this: `http://www.example.com/foo/1234/test`, the function should only return for the value `foo/*/test` instead of directly return with the `foo` value inside of the array.

So as soon as I have a string inside of the array which contains a `/` or something, I want this value to check first or give this the top prio so to speak.

Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look to this plugin : https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/, but SO is not here to make your code.

Comment: So you can sort your array by priority and then check in that order if each element appears in the URL, right?

Comment: How do you "tag" the higher importance? Because if I write an answer, then how can I be sure that it is correct with your idea?

Comment: @zvona I would use this regex to see if the matching array contains more than 1 value: `[\/](\w+)`. If so, I'd start comparing these values first agains the url.

Answer (score 0):

Since the formatting inside a reply is all messed up, I have to post it like this:

@VincentDecaux totally understand.My first thoughts would have been sth like this:

```
function checkUrl(url, arr) {
    const checkForPaths = arr.filter(val => val.match(/[\/](\w+)/ig));
     if (checkForPaths.length) {
         return true;
     }

     const filteredArray = arr.filter(val => url.includes(val));
     if (filteredArray.length) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

This might already work since I only want the function to return true/false in order to display sth. on the page depemding on this.